# Create dynamic rectangles in datawindow rows

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm trying to create dynamic rectangles to indicate a particular status of an item in a row.

The scenario is that I have a powerbuilder app that shows rows of trucks and it's loads on a timeline.

I'm currently creating the rectangles using the dw.create () function. It works .. but the rectangle I'm creating for 1 truck is replicated over all the rows. Thus load rectangle for truck 1 is also created (showing) for all the other trucks (which I don't want - as each truck has its own load rect)

How do I create a rectangle only visible for a partucular row?

kind regards
Alex

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create the rectangles 'on top' of the datawindow cell.  You would do this via a modify statement similar to:

```
    ls_modify  = 'create text(band=foreground alignment="0" text="'+ls_txt+'" '
if not lb_view_only then
    ls_modify += 'border="1" ' //border = 4 (lowered)
    ls_modify += 'resizeable=1 '
    ls_modify += 'moveable=1 '
else
    ls_modify += 'border="1" ' //border = 1 (shadowbox)     
    ls_modify += 'resizeable=0 '
    ls_modify += 'moveable=0 '
end if
ls_modify += 'color="' + string(ll_txt_color)+'" '  
ls_modify += 'x="'+string(ll_xpos1)+'" y="'+string(ll_ypos)+'" height="'+string(ll_uo_hgt)+'" '
ls_modify += 'width="'+string(ll_width)+'" html.valueishtml="0"  name='+ls_name+' visible="1" '
ls_modify += 'font.face="Arial" font.height="-8" font.weight="400" font.family="2" '
ls_modify += 'font.pitch="2" font.charset="0" background.mode="2" background.color="'+string(ll_bk_color)+'" )'
ls_rtn = dw_1.modify(ls_modify)
```

In this case you would need logic to determine the X, Y, height, and width based on the underlying cell in the datawindow.  You also need to give the object a unique name.

Comment: I continued .. below my summarized code:
for l_v_ind = 1 to l_v_cnt
 l_row = dw_list.insertRow(0)
 for l_l_ind = 1 to l_l_cnt
  block_cnt++
  s_mod = "create rectangle(band=Detail x='"+string(i_x)&
   +"' y='20' height='100' width='"+string(i_w)+"' name=r_"+string(l_load_id)"
  s_test = dw_list.Modify(s_mod) 
 next
next

Comment: My problem is that rectangles created for (row 1, vehicle 1) also appear on row 2 and so forth. 
I then added a dynamic visibility flag column int “i_”+( l_load_id) – 1 or 0 and changed the create rectangle() function to have 
visible='0 if(i"+string(l_load_id)+"=1,1,0)')"
That also seems to work as I wanted to - just feel that there is an easier way.

Comment: You could use the Status column to change the visible property of the rectangles as well.